# Babel-cli class properties are not working with stage-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have this code where I am using class properties for react component state.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

        state = {
            filter: '',
            searchTerm: ''
        }
    }
```

This code is working fine in babel-repl when I have selected presets react,stage-2. But it doesn't work when I try to transpile using babel-cli. My package.json have -

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src -d lib"
},
"babel-cli": "^6.14.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.8.0",
"babel-preset-latest": "^6.14.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.13.0"
```

And when I run `npm run build` I keep getting this error and it particularly highlights equality operator after state variable.

> SyntaxError: react/Fidelis.K2.Views.React.BrowseCommunities.js:
>
> Unexpected token (2:14)
>
> 1 | class MyComponent extends React.Component {
> 2 |     state = {
>
> 3 |       filter: '',
> 4 |       searchTerm: ''
> 5 |    }

Comment: try remove catalog node_modules, upgrade npm and node(better 6.5 not LTS) to lasted version, after install modules again and check will work.

Comment: Where are your presets configured?

Comment: node version is `4.2.1` and npm version is `3.7.0`. Presets configured are `stage-2`, `latest` & `react`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The required preset wasn't mentioned in .babelrc

Once I updated it, this was working fine. Here is my updated `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "presets":  ["latest", "react", "stage-2"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-assign"
  ]
}
```